# Python - Pandas - Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Mi duda es la siguiente.

Tengo este *DataFrame*:

```
        ESTACION  MAGNITUD   ANO  MES DIA  EMISION       FECHA
0              4         1  2016    1  01      8.0   2016-1-01
12             4         6  2016    1  01      0.4   2016-1-01
24             4         7  2016    1  01     28.0   2016-1-01
36             4         8  2016    1  01     40.0   2016-1-01
48             4        12  2016    1  01     83.0   2016-1-01
...          ...       ...   ...  ...  ..      ...         ...
225197        60         7  2019   12  31     77.0  2019-12-31
225209        60         8  2019   12  31     83.0  2019-12-31
225221        60        10  2019   12  31     25.0  2019-12-31
225233        60        12  2019   12  31    202.0  2019-12-31
225245        60        14  2019   12  31      4.0  2019-12-31

[225246 rows x 7 columns]
```

La columna 'FECHA' la incorporé utilizando el siguiente código:

```
df['FECHA'] = df.astype(str)[['ANO','MES','DIA']].apply('-'.join, axis = 1)
```

Y después lo pasé a *datetime* con el siguiente código:

```
df.FECHA = pd.to_datetime(df.FECHA,format = '%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
```

Ahora, el problema es que hay fechas que están mal, particularmente los 2-29 / 2-30 / 2-31 de cada año:

```
        ESTACION  MAGNITUD   ANO  MES DIA  EMISION      FECHA
1              4         1  2016    2  01     12.0  2016-2-01
13             4         6  2016    2  01      0.7  2016-2-01
25             4         7  2016    2  01    116.0  2016-2-01
37             4         8  2016    2  01     64.0  2016-2-01
49             4        12  2016    2  01    241.0  2016-2-01
...          ...       ...   ...  ...  ..      ...        ...
219733        60         7  2016    2  31      0.0  2016-2-31
219745        60         8  2016    2  31      0.0  2016-2-31
219757        60        10  2016    2  31      0.0  2016-2-31
219769        60        12  2016    2  31      0.0  2016-2-31
219781        60        14  2016    2  31      0.0  2016-2-31

[4681 rows x 7 columns]
```

Entonces, ¿Cómo hago para eliminarlas?, o que me aparezca `NaT` solo en aquellas fechas que están mal. Por que si por ejemplo uso el siguiente código:

```
df.FECHA = pd.to_datetime(df.FECHA,format = '%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

Me devuelve a toda la columna como `NaT`.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Puedes utilizar la propia función `astype()` para transformarlo a datetime, o también usar las funciones del modulo datetime

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion facil es hacerlo como tu lo haces, uniendo los datos con el método `apply()` y `join`, solo que en vez de crear un nuevo *DataFrame* con formato `datetime`, lo haremos con el modulo `datetime` y nuevamente con un `apply()`, esto se puede usar n veces, pues el metodo `apply()` actúa en el *DataFrame* y si se ha hecho un `apply()` antes, el siguiente `apply()` actuará en el resultado del anterior. Teniendo esa lógica podemos hacer esto

```py
from datetime import datetime #importamos datetime

df["FECHA"] = df[['ANO','MES' ,'DIA']].apply('-'.join, axis=1).apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Hola!! Muchas gracias por la respuesta!! pero lamento decir que el problema persiste jajaja, me arroja el mismo error "ValueError: day is out of range for month" que seguro salta por esos dias de febrero

Comment: mételo en un `try/except`, debería funcionar.